# Why instantiated Static Mesh gets scaled in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4, mesh, blueprints, instancing

Building a project in Unreal Engine 4.26 while trying to increase performance of the videogame I ended up using instances of static meshes where possible. This generated an issue:

**My instantiated meshes are scaled to 0.9995/1** (experimentally proven).
Looking for an answer I found a work-around suggested by Unreal Engine devs themselves: they suggested to rotate the mesh adding a rotation of 360 degree using higher values of same rotation as you can read [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/540843/instanced-static-mesh-gets-scaled.html). This didn't worked for me and, as you can see, the difference from instantiated and manually placed meshes are evident.

[image: evidence]

Following the way I've instantiated the meshes:

[image: code]

Increasing the rotation on **z-axis** using 450 degrees didn't solved anything even though doing it with the meshes provided by devs [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/540843/instanced-static-mesh-gets-scaled.html) it actually works.

I'm sure that rotations are the key to solve the problem since the problem is not systematic, I didn't get the logic behind but building a square with instantiated meshes I end up having some walls with spaces and some of them with perfect scale. I increased the size of them all so to not have spaces but I'm afraid that the solution will bring more issues in future while working with light and production materials. Seems that the bug isn't solved yet in UE4, is there another work-around that I may use without any risk of overlapping meshes?

UPDATE: Seems that I'll have issues where the meshes are overlapped since the increasing of scale is done systematically even if there's no need.

EDIT: You can reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680694/why-instantiated-static-mesh-gets-scaled-in-unreal-engine-4) to get the bounty.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a cross-post from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680694/why-instantiated-static-mesh-gets-scaled-in-unreal-engine-4

Comment: I posted it twice because I can't get an answer and I started a bounty on StackOverflow. I can't start a bounty here, but this is the proper stack exchange. What should I do?

Comment: If you want to ask the question here, the one on SO needs to be closed/deleted. If you want to ask the question on SO, this one needs to be closed/deleted.

Comment: I'll close this one here for now; If you don't get an answer on SO, then please delete the one on SO and flag for a moderator here, we'll be able to reopen it.